# Sharepoint Radiobutton New Options

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to append new options to Share point choice column shown as radio button on form.I was able to add options to the field but the form is not saving throwing validation error. Did i miss something?

Comment: Please go to list settings, select the column in question and give some more information about the settings for this column.

Comment: Hi I created a choice column and added one sample value for it (as it asks for at least one value). Now this column will be shown as radio button on form and i added dynamic options as i require but the list is not saving now

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are using script to append the choices. The new choices are not real values in this column, so that you get error.

We can save all choice values as items in a list and use the InfoPath form to dynamically display values from the list in the drop down based on conditions.

1. Customize the form for the target list using the InfoPath.
2. In the InfoPath form, add a data connection to connect “choices” list. Select the all fields you need to receive.
3. Add a drop down and select the data source created above. Filter entries based on your conditions.

[image]

4. Publish the form.

Comment: Hi Is there way to do this without Infopath. As i said i am able to append new options to Dropdown/radiobutton but the form is not saving

Comment: I mentioned above: The new choices appended using code on the page are not real values in this column, so that you get error.